# Snap 0.9 routing behavior

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I can't figure out the routing strangeness in Snap 0.9 (and, most likely, other versions)

I understand "/" is a catch everything pattern unless I put ifTop function inside the handler, right?
So, with ("/", blah) route, any URL should be handled by the blah handler, correct?

Playing with the default app generated by snap init, I can't get snap to render anything but index.tpl for the root request.

Given root ("/", blah) and handler

```
blah :: Handler App App ()
blah = render "blah"
```

it renders blah template for any URL but the root URL!
So "/anything" renders blah template but "/" renders index template.

Changing blah handler to

```
blah = ifTop $ render "blah"
```

does not change the behavior whatsoever.
Only in this case I cant route to "/anything". Routing to "/" still renders index template.
What am I missing? How can I get "/" to render template of my choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have "index.tpl" template, then it will be used to render root page anyway. The issue is `heistInit` function:

```
heistInit :: FilePath                 -- ^ Path to templates
          -> SnapletInit b (Heist b)
heistInit templateDir = do
    makeSnaplet "heist" "" Nothing $ do
        hs <- heistInitWorker templateDir defaultHeistState
        addRoutes [ ("", heistServe) ]
        return hs
```

You see that it calles `addRoutes`. So, if you call `heistInit` before adding your own routes (default template *does* that), then your handlers will not have even a chance if there is a template with the same name (or index.tpl for root).

So just place `addRoutes routes` above `heistInit` (`app` in Site.hs in default template).

Comment: Thank you. I figured that existence of the index template makes it default for the root. I am confused with your statement about match anything though ... If I have  ("/", blah) root then everything is handled by blah function excluding any other defined roots. Given the above root I can append any random string to "/" and it will be forwarded to the blah function. Any comment on this? Now, "" comes with this routing entry ("", serveDirectory "static"). So what is the difference between "" and "/" ?

Comment: I just tried. Your are right, "" and "/" are the same. I removed the statement re "" from the answer.